# How to iterate thru different filenames in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have assigned to variables different files. Now I want to make some operations iterating those variables. For example:
   `reduced_file1= 'names.xlsx'`
   `reduced_file2= 'surnames.xlsx'`
   `reduced_file3= 'city.xlsx'`
   `reduced_file4= 'birth.xlsx'`

the operations I want to iterate (with a FOR loop ) are:

`xls= pd.ExcelFile(reduced_file1)`
   `xls= pd.ExcelFile(reduced_file2)`
   `xls= pd.ExcelFile(reduced_file3)`
   `xls= pd.ExcelFile(reduced_file4)`
...and so on

Basically every time is changing the name of the variable : reduced_file(i)

Thanks

Comment: this is way below the level of a stackoverflow questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
files= ['names.xlsx', 'surnames.xlsx', 'city.xlsx', 'birth.xlsx']

for file in files:
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
```

You can also change string names by using f-strings:

```py
for i in range(4):
    print(f"this is number {i}")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!